# .htaccess - all pages except homepage to load with https

Tags: .htaccess

I have redirected all pages to use https using the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Is there a way I can exclude the homepage from this?  So everything apart from www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com load using https?

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding this line before `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
```

**Edit**

If the above doesn't work, try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.php|)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Notes:

1. I assume you're running a PHP application server, thus there is an `index.php` file in the document root that will be served when someone requests `/`; otherwise, replace `index\.php` with your DirectoryIndex file (e.g. `index\.html`, don't forget the backslash to escape the dot)
2. I added a [L] (last) flag to the rewrite directive to make the rewrite engine stop here in the rewriting process, when it finds a match. To learn more, see the Rewriterule reference ([Apache 2.0 link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule))

Comment: Hi Paolo, this just seems to break my site so that no pages will load

Comment: @bland_dan I edited my answer, and tested the part after "edit" on a WAMP server. In fact the first solution didn't work, the second does.